# Tomcat: Setting port in server.xml does not work

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I've been running a web app on Eclipse/IntelliJ via Tomcat with the server instance set to port 8080.
Running the app using the .war file via startup.bat is running it on 8095 instead (by default). However, I want the .war to run on 8080 as well.

I went to conf/server.xml and changed the Connector to port 8080. However, now the app doesn't run - it hangs on making a request to the localhost and never manages to make it.

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Could someone with more experience in web apps suggest what might be blocking it from running on 8080 from the war file?

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after changing the port?

Comment: Yep, I had Tomcat turned off when I made the change.

Comment: Does tomcat start, which port is it listening to?

Comment: You need to describe the symptoms more fully. If the problem were merely the web browser using one port and the server using another port, there would be no “it hangs”. The web browser would immediately report that no server responds at that address/port. Voting to close for lack of debugging details.